# UIGestureRecognizer Detection Order

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Okay, I have a viewA with the subView viewB. Both of them have a gestureRecognizer assigned to them. Now I'm using

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

to be able to call both of them at the same time. Now let's say that if `gestureRecognizer` gets activated, it calls

```
NSLog(@"This is...");
```

And if `otherGestureRecognizer` gets activated it calls

```
NSLog(@"Sparta!");
```

The Problem is that if both gestureRecognizers get activated at the same time, there's no order in which they are called, so sometimes

```
NSLog(@"Sparta!");
```

gets called first and sometimes it's the other way round. Is there a way to make sure that

```
NSLog(@"This is...");
```

*always* gets called first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up lowering the minimum press duration of the UIGestureRecognizer that should be called first just a millisecond, that did the job

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?
You are trying to make your subview the firstresponder but have your parentview respond after that as well? So that you have both responses but in a fixed order?

If so you can make a gesturerecognizer on both views. check for the first response (which should be your subview I suppose) and then make a delegate protocol to have its parent respond to this "change" as well.

Anyway some more explanation on your part could be useful to be exactly sure.